# Which request is my onReceive answering to?

Tags: android, sms, arraylist, android-pendingintent

I have an ArrayList of contacts that contains a phone number and a status field.  I want to update the status field on a successful send result.

I even tried passing the index of the ArrayList item in to the Pending Intent with contacts.indexOf(c.getPhoneNumber()) as the int requestCode.  I just cant' figure out how to tell which message is reporting back as successful and update my contact item.

```
package com.example.SMS;

public class SendSMSActivity extends SMSActivity {

    private EditText smsMessageBody;
    private Button send_button;
    private SmsManager sms;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sendsmsactivity);

        setupViews();

    }

    private void setupViews() {

        smsMessageBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsText_editText1);
        broadcast_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendsms_button);

        send_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (smsMessageBody.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                    if (!getSendSMSApplication().getCurrentContacts().isEmpty()) {
                        sendSMSLoop();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.messages_sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        getSendSMSApplication().setCurrentContacts(null);  //  Clear existing contacts after send
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.error_no_numbers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }   //  there are phone numbers to send to?
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.error_no_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }   //  user entered a message?
            }
        });

    }

    protected void sendSMSLoop() {

        ArrayList<ContactItem> contacts = getSendSMSApplication().getCurrentContacts();

        for (ContactItem c:contacts) {
            sendSMS(c.getPhoneNumber().toString(), smsMessageBody.getText().toString(), contacts.indexOf(c.getPhoneNumber()));
        }

    }

    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message, int messageIndex)
    {        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, messageIndex, new Intent(SENT), 0);


        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.sms_sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some code taken from my actual code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        if (messages.length > -1) {
//The 2 variables you need (from and body)
messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
messages[0].getMessageBody();
...
```

Try passing the received/delivered intent to this function (complete the function to add the functionality you need), I will be trying it in a few weeks time so let me know how it goes if you beat me to it.

Just re-looked over your code...

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
```

My code looks more like:

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

You need to add the extra intent to work with the pdus, as far as I am aware.

Comment: I was able to receive "sent" and "delivered" information, but I didn't know how to tell sent- or delivered- for which send.  I also have a deliveredPI, but I removed it as it wasn't relevant unless I could actually determine from which intent.  If nothing else your code above is a great hint.  Short of solutions that's all I generally need :)  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think we might be able to mutually benefit each other on this one, I have a way of telling apart the sent and delivered intents pretty easily, do you have skype? - messaged you from your contact form on your website.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to do this myself at the moment. I guess you have got the same problem as me and if you are sending more than 1 message, they are all returning the same sent code for all 3 messages. I think the trick here is to 'thread' each message so that each 'thread' will have a different return code. I can't guarantee this is the solution but it is the path I am next going to go down for solving this issue.

Hope this helps, if you work it out please let me know too.

Comment: Would you mind deleting your answer and just favoriting the question if you want to follow along?  I don't think I'm getting much activity because this shows up as answered in the list.  I'll definitely keep you in mind if an answer is found.  Thanks Dech!

Comment: Bill, I think my lecturer at uni has explained this to me a bit better now. Have you got to the stage of getting the receive/delivered intent? One of them (think it is the latter) "has extras" one of which is possibly the PUDS. This should contain the message/sender/some kind of identifying information. I have had to switch my Courswork for a bit but I think I am almost at a solution. Hope this helps you out.